# Boost recursive variant

Tags: c++, boost, variant

What I want to do is essentially (simplified but reproduces issue):

```
using my_variant_t = variant<int, function<void (recursive_wrapper<my_variant_t>)>>;
```

That is, a variant that can be an int, or a function that accepts the same type of variant as an argument. But this fails, of course, because `‘my_variant_t’ was not declared in this scope`. OK, so next I try `make_recursive_variant`.

```
using my_variant_t = make_recursive_variant<int, function<void (recursive_variant_)>>::type;
```

This compiles. So far so good. But when I try to use it...

```
my_variant_t x = [](my_variant_t p) {};
```

Then it fails with... a whole lot of compiler output... but I think `Failed to specialize function template` is the important bit.

Through trial and error, I discovered that I could get it to compile if I instead wrote the lambda like this:

```
my_variant_t x = [](recursive_variant_ p) {};
```

But that's not what I would have expected. Based on the documentation, I expected to be able to reference the result variant type `my_variant_t`. And even worse, when I try to invoke this lambda...

```
x(42);
```

Then it fails with `no match for call`.

I assume I'm missing something or misusing variant in some way. Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

You're simply expecting too much of the recursive variant placeholder system.

It's one thing for the library to spot and substitute types in a template argument list (like `std::vector<_>`, where `_` is e.g. the `recursive_variant_` placeholder).

It's another thing entirely to expect placeholders to be detected (and replaced) inside *function signatures* that go inside template argument lists.

I'm not sure it could be done, but it would be pretty hard (to get right and hard on the compiler during compilation)

Comment: Indeed, I think it's a limitation of the mpl placeholders, they work in templates like `x<_1>`, `x<_1,_2>` but not `x<_1(_2)>`. Luckily there is a form of `boost::function` that takes the signature of the stored function as a sequence of types ( [`function1<void,recursive_variant_>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e13873ed6fb9784)). About the function call operator, he can't use it like that because `variant` does not have it defined, he would need to use a visitor, but I'm not sure it makes sense (how do you call `3(42)`? or `f(42)` (where f takes a `function<void(int)> as argument)?).

Comment: @cv_and_he ✔ Using the boost function1 did the trick. You're also right that invoking the variant function is tricky. I had to very ugly write it as `boost::get<function1<void, my_variant_t>>(x)(42);`